# Problems with Set<>.contains and hashCode

Tags: java, set, hashcode

I have a `Set<SelectDTO>` with a single element and I'm failing when using .contains with it and a new SelectDTO, as follows:

```
Set<SelectDTO> setDTOs = new HashSet<SelectDTO>
//processing where an element with <name = "ME101", id = 102> is added.

SelectDTO selectDTO = new SelectDTO();
selectDTO.setName("ME101");
selectDTO.setId(102);
if (!setDTOs.contains(selectDTO)){
     throw new Exception();
}
```

I have override SelectDTO's `.hashCode()`, so that it's calculated as the sum of the parameters id and name. I have debugged and confirmed that the execution goes through `.hashCode()` two times: the first when the element is added to the set and the second when calling `.contains()`. Both elements' hashCode is -2024486876. But also, when debugging, I see that the table within the set has a single element, its "hash" being -1909995738.

This is the code for my hashCode, although I don't think the problem's there:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 0;
    result += this.getName() != null ? this.getName().hashCode() : 0;
    result += this.getId() != null ? this.getId() : 0;
    return result;
}
```

I guess that `.contains()` is using this 'hash' value to compare, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Set.contains() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Returns `true` if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this set contains an element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

In other words, you do not only need to implement `hashCode()`, but also `equals()`.

Comment: That's it. `equals()` had already been overridden and I assumed it was comparing fields, but it looks like it's comparing references too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to add the selectDTO  element in Set:

```
setDTOs.add(selectDTO);
```

Assuming you have added the element somewhere in your code, then you need to override the equals method and not hashCode. As [contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method uses [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to determine whether an element exist or not in the set. Interestingly, i believe this is how Set makes sure it does not push a duplicate element in the Set.

Comment: No, it's added but not shown here. In the part where I say //processing

Comment: According to the question, the element is added to the set (see second line of first code block).

Comment: @mthmulders Updated my answer on the basis of comment received by the questioner